# Creating versioning and oauth2 based authentication with my existing project on cakephp 2.0 to laravel 5

Tags: php, rest, laravel, oauth, cakephp-2.0

I am upgrading from Cakephp 2.0 to Laravel 5.1. I need to do versioning if some one can suggest whether it should be in URI or headers?

How to maintain previous login databases of users info with Cakephp hashes to new Laravel oauth2.

Please help me find good reference for this and best practices to write code using repos, services and libraries.

I found this package [Laravel oauth2 server](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel)

But could not find anything for better versioning where I do not need to repeat whole code.

Thanks in advance.

A article on REST API [Best way to write rest api](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it.For password i used

[Using passwords hashed in CakePHP in Laravel environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821896/using-passwords-hashed-in-cakephp-in-laravel-environment)

For Oauth i used the same package mentioned above using password auth and for API versioning i followed laracasts series.